# Nothing displays onscreen when attempting to render a Vertex Buffer Object via OpenGL

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I am trying to switch my OpenGL application from the old fixed function system to using Vertex Buffer Objects. However, with my current setup nothing is displaying on the screen. I'm sure I'm making some simple error, but I can't see it.

[gltest.h](http://pastebin.com/Kdbx8FmZ)
[gltest.cpp](http://pastebin.com/nprgBDRZ)

`model` and `index` hold the IDs for my vbo and ibo respectively. The buffer objects are set up in the `GLTest::makeModel` method. The struct i'm using to store vertex data has 3 floats for the position, followed by 4 unsigned chars for the color.

It creates three vertices arranged in a triangle, and the buffer object simply contains the numbers 0,1,and 2. I call the method with a QRgb object containing the color blue, so with this setup, I would expect to see a blue triangle displayed on screen. Instead, nothing is displayed.

A full Qt project which shows the error is available [here](http://www.mediafire.com/?aost3weo98hoo17). You will need GLEW installed.

Comment: Rather than posting links to code/project, post snippets of relevant code. For example, post the code where you initialize/generate the VBO, the code where you draw the VBO, and any associated error messages.

Comment: Does your code work without VBOs ? Meaning - with just vertex arrays ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never programmed with the fixed-pipeline versions of OpenGL, but I've been doing lots of work in v3.0+, so take my advice carefully!

You seem to be mixing old and new together, for example you don't have a vertex or fragment shader loaded.  Your `glEnableClientState()`, `glMatrixMode()`, `glLoadIdentity()`, `glVertexPointer()`, `glColorPointer()` are depreciated in modern OpenGL; having been replaced by shader functionality.

Also whenever I get stuck with this sort thing, I litter my gl calls with glGetError(), you only have one.

Comment: Whereas using the fixed-function pipeline is deprecated, it should perfectly work. Of course you can use VBOs without shaders and his code indeed looks quite reasonable. I don't know where he is mixing old and new together, he's just using the old stuff. So I don't think this answers his question, but the general tip about `glGetError` is of course a good one.

Comment: I was just following several tutorials which all listed generally the same things. The code I posted here is a stripped down version of my main program, which actually does use this code along with vertex and fragment shaders. The end result is the same there, where absolutely nothing displays on the screen. I decided to exclude the shaders here.

How are you meant to specify the projection matrix without `glMatrixMode()` and `glLoadIdentity()`?

Comment: You construct a matrix yourself and pass it into your vertex shader as a uniform.

Comment: This didn't exactly answer the question, but my goal from the start was to rid myself of all the deprecated OpenGL calls, and doing additional research to get rid of the calls you mentioned ended up helping me solve the problem.

Comment: In cases like these it may be better to 'answer' the question yourself, describing what you did to solve it.  Not that I'd turn down rep points...